# How to be relieved of pain with in-grown nails?

Tags: infection, feet

I have an in-grown nail on my toe and I don't know what to do. I'm aware that seeing a podiatrist(?) might help but I don't want my nail getting removed (yet) because I have a swimming class. They say upon recovery, the said nail isn't allowed to get wet. Are there any options for at least a temporary relief?

Comment: Hi! If your in-grown nail hurts, it could mean that it is infected or has an abscess (=paronychia). In that case, I would suggest to see your GP, who will perhaps have to do a drainage. Note that in some cases of acute paronychia, no "surgical intervention" is needed,  and warm water soaks 3-4 times per day +/- antibiotics might be enough (this depends on your risk factors, eg diabetes etc). But again, I would suggest you see a specialist. Good luck. Best regards. M. Arrowsmith (N.B this question could be seen as asking for personal medical advice and might be seen as off topic here)

Answer (score 2):

I've had ingrown nails for more than 15 years and complete nail removal was never on the table. Wedge resection is a much more easy procedure, which may not even require anesthesia. It will also heal much faster and will hardly interfere with your everyday life.

More on this procedure can be found at:

1. [Advice for parents about wedge resection of toenail](https://www.derbyhospitals.nhs.uk/easysitewe/getresource.axd?assetid=281947&type=0&servicetype=1)
2. [Ingrown Toenail Removal](http://www.aafp.org/afp/2002/0615/p2547.html)

EDIT: this procedure is less invasive, but recurrence is quite common.

Comment: Any references to support this?

Comment: As I said, I get this basically for the treatment I've followed to keep my nails at bay. I found a couple of useful links regarding this pocedure though: https://www.derbyhospitals.nhs.uk/easysiteweb/getresource.axd?assetid=281947&type=0&servicetype=1
http://www.bmj.com/content/344/bmj.e2089
http://www.aafp.org/afp/2002/0615/p2547.html

I have also edited my answer to cover the fact that recurrence might be an issue.

Comment: Those are some very comprehensive resources, +1, and since comments might be deleted, while the answer is more permanent and it is health SE policy that all answers should be substantiated with reliable references, I've added your references into the body of the answer.